# how to solve Ignoring exception, response committed already: http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have this error after creating a cart for the customer  i tried to use json ignore but nothing worked with me

and the error keep coming out and does not sending cart  items to front end but the backend console shows cartItems
error :

```
2024-03-24T04:26:08.918Z  WARN 10356 --- [nio-8020-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Ignoring exception, response committed already: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
2024-03-24T04:26:08.918Z  WARN 10356 --- [nio-8020-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)]
```

my CartItem model :

```
package com.ecommerce.library.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart_items")
public class CartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shopping_cart_id", referencedColumnName = "shopping_cart_id")
    private ShoppingCart cart;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private double unitPrice;
    private String username;
    private String color;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CartItem{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", cart=" + cart.getId() +
                ", product=" + product.getName() +
                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                ", unitPrice=" + unitPrice +
                ", totalPrice=" +
                '}';
    }

    public void getUnitPrice(double price) {
    }

    public void getUsername(String userId) {
    }

}
```

Shoppingcart :

```
package com.ecommerce.library.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "shopping_cart")
public class ShoppingCart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "shopping_cart_id")
    private Long id;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
    private String username;

    private double totalPrice;

    private int totalItems;
    private Long userId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cart", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

    public ShoppingCart() {
        this.cartItems = new HashSet<>();
        this.totalItems = 0;
        this.totalPrice = 0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShoppingCart{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", customer=" + customer.getUsername() +
                ", totalPrice=" + totalPrice +
                ", totalItems=" + totalItems +
                ", cartItems=" + cartItems.size() +
                '}';
    }


}
```

creating cart :

```
            shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
            shoppingCart.setCustomer(customer);
            shoppingCart.setUsername(customer.getUsername());
            shoppingCart = cartRepository.save(shoppingCart);
            customer.setCart(shoppingCart);
```

i want to know to solve this problem i tied to use **@JsonBackReference & @JsonManagedReference & @JsonIgnore**